# Delete all characters from cursor to } with TeXStudio Script

Tags: texstudio

> I'd like to write a script that deletes all characters between cursor position and '}' character or the end of line.

Just an example (`_` is the position of cursor):

`\section{hello}_\label{hello} %comment`

becomes

`\section{hello} %comment`

---

I tried this code:

```
%SCRIPT
do {
cursor.deleteChar(); 
}
while (cursor.nextChar()!='}'||!cursor.atLineEnd() )
```

but TeXStudio stops working!

Comment: I think that the algorithm is correct but there are some mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found mistakes!
This is the working script. Of course, any suggestion is well accepted!

```
do{
cursor.deleteChar();
nextChar = String.fromCharCode(cursor.nextChar());
}while(nextChar!='}'&&!(cursor.atLineEnd()));
cursor.deleteChar();
```